# Changing the Columns through a loop - VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I have this code for pasting the "sum" formula at the same row but in diferent columns (actually, is not this exactly formula, the "sum" was used only for explaining)

```
for i = 1 to 100
Cells(2, (1 + 5 * (i - 1))).Formula = "=sum($A$1:$E$1)"
Next
```

But, I need this formula to change every iteration, like the cell that it is pasted. Then, the Cell `"A1"` (`for i = 1`) must change to `"F1"` at the same moment as `"E1"` change to `"J1"` when `i = 2`. 
How can I make this loop through columns?

Thanks in advance!

Luiz

Comment: What is the exact logic for the incrementation of the formula ? It's not clear to me from your example what your logic is.

Comment: It adds 5 columns ! A -> E; F -> J!
Got it?
When i = 3: E + 5 column = I and F +5 = N !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i = 1 to 100
    Cells(2, 5 + ((i - 1) * 5)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-1]C[-4]:R[-1]C[0])"
Next
```

Comment: Dude, I'm sorry, but what is this?

Comment: Dude, did you try it?  `FormulaR1C1` uses relative addressing, so that's entering a SUM for the range beginning one row above (-1 offset) and four columns to the left (-4 offset), and ending at the cell one row above and in the same column (zero offset)

Comment: It will only be possible to try tomorrow. Sorry about that. But thanks a lot for your reply!

I just couldnt understand how to it works !! but i'm looking at google

Comment: I just dont understand why you changed `Cells(2, (1 + 5 * (i - 1)))` to `Cells(2, 5 + ((i - 1) * 5))`.

Using my reference to cells, it gaves a error ! (yours run, but it start giving me the formula 1 iteration after I want)

Comment: Don't worry about that - just use whatever works for you.  I was assuming the formula would go directly under the last cell in each range being summed...

Comment: Well done! With only a few arrangemets, it works perfectly!
Thanks a lot for your effort and for your exaplaination about R1C1 notation!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
 Dim colChar As String, colChar5 As String
    For i = 1 To 100 Step 5
        colChar = Split(Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
        colChar5 = Split(Cells(, i + 4).Address, "$")(1)
        Cells(2, i).Formula = "=sum(" & colChar & "1:" & colChar5 & "1)"
    Next
```

Comment: Wow, it also worked! but the @Tim Williams way was clearer!
Anyway, thanks a lot! very helpful!

Comment: Unfortunatelly it seems that I can only choose one answer, but I would accept yours too!

Comment: @Luiz Even i would prefer tim answer but its just an alternative. Annyways you can vote this answer.